# How does list1 == list2.reverse() gets executed in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to compare two lists(as shown) and I have written a code based on my own logic. According to my logic I have to get output as 'Yes' but I am getting 'No' as output. I think there is something wrong in line3 of my code. According to my logic, in line 3, list2 gets reversed first and then it is compared with list1. With this logic, I have to get output as 'Yes'. Is my logic correct? If not please help me how line3 gets executed.(I am new to python)

```
list1 = ['a','m','y']
list2 = ['y','m','a']
if list1 == list2.reverse():
    print('Yes')
else:
    print("No")
```

Given Output: No;
Expected Output: Yes

Comment: The value returned by the reverse method is **not** the reversed list: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types

Comment: `.reverse ` reverses the original list it doesn't return a new **reversed list**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list2.reverse() will not return anything i.e. None, but it modifies your list
below is the correct code:

```
list1 = ['a','m','y']
list2 = ['y','m','a']
list2.reverse()
if list1 == list2:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

because `list2.reverse()` returns 'None' and it change `list2`to `['a','m','y']`. Use this ->

```
 list2 = ['y','m','a']
 list2.reverse()
 if list1 == list2:
    print('Yes')
 else:
    print("No")
```

Answer (score 0):

you might code like below:

```
list1 = ['a','m','y']
list2 = ['y','m','a']
list2.reverse()
if list1 == list2:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print("No")
>>> Yes
```

Or like this:

```
list1 = ['a','m','y']
list2 = ['y','m','a']
if list1 == list(reversed(list2)):
    print('Yes')
else:
    print("No")
```